# Is it ok to use two sodimm with diferent mhz?

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr3

I have a laptop memory but it was damaged. So I temporary used another sodimm memory which is 2GB DDR3(10600) and I'm planning to buy a new one.

Is it ok to use a sodimm memory which is 4GB DDR3(12800) together with my temporary memory? 
Since my original memory used is 4GB DDR3 (12800).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can work if the motherboard supports PC3-10600 modules. Check it with motherboard manual or manufacturer site.

Theoretically, it should work. Because both support (8-8-8, 9-9-9, 10-10-10) timings Timings (CL-tRCD-tRP). However, the overall memory will run at the lowest speed among the memory modules, in which case 1333.3 (MT/s).

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Modules

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

The memory speed quoted is the fastest that it can run at.

When paired with slower memory it will run at the lower speed.